# How to use excel 2010 functions to calculate the sum of distinct unique values?

Tags: excel-formula, unique, distinct

1. remove the duplicate values
2. sum of distinct unique values
   but I don't need to know who are the distinct unique values, I just need the sum

Example:

```
A1  1
A2  2
A3  2
A4  3
A5  3
A6  3
A7  4
A8  4
A9  4
A10 4
```

`sum = 1+2+3+4 = 10`

I know it may involve excel functions such as SUM, IF, FREQUENCY, MATCH, ROW, etc. But I don't know how to put them together and whatever I try there will be errors. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What is a "distinct unique value" and how does it differ from a merely distinct value or a unique value?

Comment: distinct unique value is to remove the duplicate values and only count one for each duplicates. In the example, there are 2 2s, 3 3s, we only count one 2 and one 3 as the distinct unique value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a UDF I wrote for myself a while back. It will add the unique values in any 2D range.

```
Public Function SUMU(ByVal r As Range) As Double

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Volatile

    Dim nUniques() As Double
    Dim v As Variant, vValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long, nCount As Long
    Dim bMatch As Boolean

    vValues = r.Value

    If r.Count = 1 Then
        SUMU = r.Value
        Exit Function
    End If

    nCount = 1
    ReDim nUniques(1 To 1)
    For Each v In vValues
        If v <> "" And IsNumeric(v) Then
            bMatch = False
            For i = LBound(nUniques) To UBound(nUniques)
                If v = nUniques(i) Then
                    bMatch = True
                End If
            Next i
            If bMatch = False Then
                nUniques(nCount) = v
                nCount = nCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve nUniques(1 To nCount)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    SUMU = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(nUniques)

End Function
```